# How to reduce fatigue after office?

Tags: nutrition, sleep, exercise, fatigue

I work 9-6 in a software company. There's not much physical movement in office. I experience fatigue on reaching home. What can I do on weekends and even weekdays so that I don't feel tired after coming home from office?

Comment: Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: @Narusan Please can you tell what specifics should I add?

Comment: I think general fatique is just too broad and has too many causes. If you are talking about mental fatique, you could ask for improving long time concentration. For physical tiredness, ask a question in this way.

Comment: Usual causes of tiredness are: Lack of sleep, lack of good/enough food and lack of exercise.

Comment: You're asking for advice, which is off topic. It's also purely opinion and too broad.

Answer (score 2):

- Good breathing exercises keeps your lympha in motion and is good for cleaning and detoxing as well as making you in a better calmer state. When the fluid is in motion the body is too.
- Exercise in between every other 15 minutes is super important. If you can, try work while standing. Do some stretching, 3x10 squats and get your body moving. I always work out directly after work, that makes me more alert and
  not that tired, I know it's difficult to push me go to the gym but do
  a workout that's fun, crossfit? Do some strength training and some cardio afterwards for 15 minutes and enjoy a good meal after that.
- I'd also say that nutrition could be an 80% factor, avoid sugar in the morning, what do you eat for breakfast for example? Eat eggs, yoghurt, seeds (I do pumpkin+sunflower seeds), oats and good stuff. Avoid juice (sugar) and processed stuff. Lunch, eat a lean lunch that's not that huge and you'll get food coma, I eat salad, light protein and light grains (quinoa, brown rice, pasta). Maybe do a mozzarella salad or so. Pizza, burger and fatty stuff...avoid. Try eat as natural as possible. Have some nuts as a snack and drink a coffee after work and go to the gym :)

Nutrition is So important here! PM me if you want and I'll help ya! 
Cheers!

Comment: Thank you! That was about physical fatigue. How about mental fatigue?

Comment: Youre welcome! I know yoga helps people, myself I've only done breathing exercises like breath slowly through your nose and inhale, keep it there for 5-7 seconds and then breath out naturally via mouth. If you do that minimum of 10-20 times, that will absolutely help you and stay focused.

I listen to music everywhere I go, not trying to think about work and listen to stuff that makes me happy and getting to another dimension (I love 80's music, sound design and soundtrack). Try Ulrich Schnauss albums, Yann Tiersen, Electric Youth, Ben Lukas Boysen ...what more, yeah.
Ur body needs a pause.

Comment: also, try to relax, I also can find myself in my bed or couch, laying down and trying to "pause" and relax with my body, every body part from top to toe and just relax 100%, every muscle and every part of me. That helps.
Listen to calm music, maybe some Bach piano sonatas or partitas? :)
Cello suites are also good. 
I'd say breathing exercises for 15 mins, easy yoga movements and also some relaxing and laying down, good relaxing music. :) 
Watch some series on HBO or Netflix, documentaries and just change world :)

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE. Since health is an important topic, the site has a strict policy that all answers should be [backed up with reliable references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers), in order to provide the community with the means to assess the merit of the answer, regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-are-reliable-sources)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help].

Answer (score -2):

I do software as apart of my job, and I drink tea, coffee, eat icecream as an antidepressant,  have warm baths with sea salt, go for a walk every day and 1-4 fishing per year, you need a medical examination, if you feel really bad to treat progressing diseases, you need clean oxygen, comfortable sleep and clean water and food to restore yourself

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE. Since health is an important topic, the site has a strict policy that all answers should be [backed up with reliable references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers), in order to provide the community with the means to assess the merit of the answer, regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-are-reliable-sources)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help].